# How to check if elements of 2 lists are contained within the other?

Tags: java, list

I'd like to verify if each element contained in a `List<String>` is contained in any element of a 2nd list.

Example:

```
[hotel, appartment]
[hotel, appart]
```

Analye:

```
hotel      <> hotel  -> OK  (100% match)
appartment <> hotel  -> NOK 
appartment <> appart -> OK  ("appartment" is not contained in "appart", but the other way around)
```

whereas `<>` reads: either of both is included in the other string.

How could this be done best, especially from point of performance?
Is there already a apache commons or guava function handling these cases?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Does an empty string match anything?  I doubt there is a library to do this already.  I also suspect that unless you have measured a performance problem, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: When you say "contains" do you mean like String.contains e.g. "apartment" contains "artmen" or you do mean "startsWith" as in "hot" <> "hotel"

Comment: I really mean "contains" like "artmen" is contained in "appartment". It will be used for proximity judgement lateron.

Comment: So you can loop  through the Strings, looking for matches based on contains.

Comment: Oh; your dual use of "contained" was confusing. You could perhaps store the superstring list in a modified [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) of sorts, for fast lookups of substrings. But you should be sure your performance requirements aren't being met, that your bottleneck is here, and that your program is actually complete and functioning correctly before doing this, and prefer clarity over optimization.

Comment: Are your lists sorted? Sorting will help massively, rather than iterating through them.

Comment: Sorting will help massively, rather than iterating through lsist. 
Just sort the list you are comparing against, and then use binary search to find 100% matches. (See **Collections.sort()** and **Collections.binarySearch()**. Searching for partial matches i.e. substrings of a string would require some modifications to this routine (as in searching for all possible substrings of a string in your sorted list).
Perhaps you can sort the list you are comparing against during its creation, so that verification will not incur the sorting cost.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you are looking for?
i did not run this code, just wrote it on notepad...

```
for(int a=0;a<listA.size();a++){
    for(int b=0;b<listB.size();b++){
        if(listA.get(a).equals(listB.get(b))){
            System.out.println(listA.get(a) + "<>" + listB.get(b) + " -> OK  (100% match)");
        }else{
            //if not match, check if contained
            if(listA.get(a).indexOf(listB.get(b))!=-1 || listB.get(b).indexOf(listA.get(a))!=-1){
                System.out.println(listA.get(a) + "<>" + listB.get(b) + " -> OK  ("appartment" is not contained in "appart", but the other way around)");
            }else{
                System.out.println(listA.get(a) + "<>" + listB.get(b) + " -> NOK ");
            }
        }
    }//for list B
}//for list A
```

Comment: Please note that *listA.get(a)* and *listB.get(b)* will be expensive for *LinkeList* as in **O(n)**, while for **ArrayList** *get(index)* costs **O(1)**. Even then the suggested solution has quadratic time complexity, which could be too expensive for high **N** and **M** (sizes of the lists).